# Docker cp: Error response from daemon: lstat no such file or directory

Tags: shell, ubuntu, docker, containers

I'm learning about containers docker, I'm still in the basics.. When I try to use the command `docker cp`,to copy an file from the container to the local host direcotory the output returns an error.
I type:

```
docker cp bridge:/home/arq3.txt .
```

the output:

> Error response from daemon: lstat
> /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/231afc03ee896d66b09ed3c4d1d057a73eeed4f6182c3108dcbfb5b3337c8fa5/home/arq3.txt:
> no such file or directory

Second the documentation of docker the syntax is right, so what I doing wrong? And what is this directory `var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/231afc03ee896d66b09ed3c4d1d057a73eeed4f6182c3108dcbfb5b3337c8fa5/`?

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you that there is no file `/home/arq3.txt` in your Docker container. Check the file path. The file is probably not in `/home` but in `/home/<user>` or in `/root`.

As for `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/231afc03ee896d66b09ed3c4d1d057a73eeed4f6182c3108dcbfb5b3337c8fa5`, it is the mount point of your Docker file hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when manually removed files from /var/lib/docker/aufs

To get docker functional back I had to remove all images and all container

```
docker ps -asq | xargs docker rm -f
```

Afterward, I've removed all images

```
docker images -q | xargs docker rmi
```

And then restarted all docker containers I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is there.  It is the docker name ("bridge") that is wrong.  You probably did like me and ran `docker ps` to get a list of images, then - logically - used the image name to connect.

The problem is that you started a new image and it has a different name.  You want to open a different ssh connection while Docker is running and run `docker ps` again.  This time you will see an additional image name.  Use the new one and the `docker cp` command should work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing "/app" tag in the beginning. Try following command -

```
docker cp bridge:/app/home/arq3.txt .
```

Earlier I was using following command to find location of a file -

```
docker exec -it bridge /bin/sh
```

When I tried following command, it showed "/app" directory

```
docker exec -it bridge /bin/bash
```